# Build objects depending on some others objects in blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor

In order to try the events in order to learn, I would like to build a pong game.
So I would like to create the area A, then both rackets R1 and R2, which initial position depends on the area size, then a ball B, which initial position depends on left racket position.

So it could be like this  :

```
A area = new A(width, height)
R r1 = new R(left, area.Width, area.Height)
R r2 = new R (right, area.Width, area.Height)
B ball= new B(r1.Width, r1.Height, r1.Yposition)
```

But I was unable to build the four objects in the blazor component because of initialize issues, even if I have put the code  in the OnInitialized{Async} method.

So I have made a singleton service which groups all objects in one …but it was not I would like to do because I want to trigger events from separate objects themselves.

I wonder if I would like to do is possible (creating those 4 separated objects), and how to implement it in blazor ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why can't you define the four objects as read-only class level objects and then initialize them in the Ctor?  Components are just standard classes.

Comment: Hi, sorry but what is Ctor ? The component itself ? 
My first attempt was to define classes into the class component and then to put the code above in the component but I have some errors about initializing.

Comment: See my answer. below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably not told the whole story which is why you're having problems, but based on the information you're provided, you should be able to set up the objects in the component constructor.  Components are only normal classes.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private readonly Area _area;
    private readonly Ball _ball;
    private readonly Racket _racketOne;
    private readonly Racket _racketTwo;


    public Index()
    {
        // Set th default values
        _area = new();
        _racketOne = new();
        _racketTwo = new();
        _ball = new();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //  Set any values that you get from Parameters here
    }

    public class Area {  }

    public class Racket { }

    public class Ball { }
}
```

Comment: Thank’s a lot ! It was the solution. Perfect :)